# Rails help simple form: NoMethodError in Konkurrancers#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with simple form for, I get this error url(http://localhost:3000/konkurrencer/new):
Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/konkurrancers/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

```
undefined method `konkurrancers_path' for #<#<Class:0x382ea08>:0x382d4a8>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= simple_form_for(@konkurrancer) do |f| %>
2:     <%= f.error_messages %>
3:     <%= f.input :name %>
4:     <%= f.input :banner1 %>
```

My model konkurrancer.rb

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ratings
belongs_to :kategori
validates_presence_of :name, :tracking, :banner1, :banner2, :kategori_id, :udtraekkes, :arrangeor
has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true
end
```

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@konkurrancer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :banner1 %>
    <%= f.input :banner2 %>
    <%= f.input :tracking %>
    <%= f.input :arrangeor %>
    <%= f.input :vaerdi %>
    <%= f.input :udtraekkes %>
    <%= f.association :kategori %>
    <%= f.input :note %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
  def new
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancer }
    end
  end
```

My route.rb

```
resources :konkurrencer, :controller => 'konkurrancers'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have defined `koncurrancer` as a resource in `config/routes.rb`. Only if you define it as a resource, you will get `koncurrancers_path` helper method defined. You should add

```
map.resources :koncurrancers
```

to your `routes.rb` file

Comment: rename `:konkurrencer` to `:konkurrancers`

Comment: It works if I use resources :konkurrancers. But why dosent it work when I use resources :konkurrencer, :controller => 'konkurrancers' ?

Comment: see [link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes)